# SQL: Get unique data between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am using a mysql table "student" which has 4 columns:

```
Id Name   Date          StudentId
1  John   2010-01-15      3
2  Matt   2010-01-10      5
3  Jane   2010-02-10      8
4  John   2010-02-11      3
5  Matt   2010-02-11      5
6  Jane   2010-02-11      8
```

I want to fetch only new entries in the table between 2010-02-10 and 2010-02-12. If a student had a previous entry in the table then the query should not return that value. So in the above case the query should only return both entries of Jane since John and Matt had an entry each previous to the date specified.

This is what I have but it is not working:

```
SELECT *  FROM student 
WHERE date(Date) 
between '2010-02-10' and '2010-02-12' 
and date(Date) 
not between '0000-00-00' and '2015-02-09';
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: if you want unique data, use either `DISTINCT` or do a `GROUP BY column`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  the output is basically same as SELECT *  FROM student 
WHERE date(Date) 
between '2010-02-10' and '2010-02-12';

Comment: Try using `NOW()` instead of `'0000-00-00'` if that's what you want to do here. Maybe even invert it, along with my other comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Adding one more column to the above table so as to make my case clear:                                                                                                                6 Jane 2010-02-11 8.  This should still me return me Jane . If I use distinct will that still happen ?

Comment: give it a try and see

Comment: DISTINCT fetches all unique entries in table viz John, Matt and Jane but doesn't filter by date! BTW 0000-00-00 is to represent date of first record in table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` is what you are looking for if you want single record per student:

```
SELECT * FROM student 
  GROUP BY Name 
  HAVING DATE(Date) BETWEEN '2010-02-10' AND '2010-02-12';
```

Or I would use subquery if you want all the records:

```
SELECT * FROM student 
  WHERE DATE(Date) BETWEEN '2010-02-10' AND '2010-02-12'
  AND Name NOT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM student WHERE DATE(Date) < '2010-02-10');
```

*How it works:*
the subquery selects all the names that have records prior to the date range, i.e. the ones you don't want in your result. It produces set like `('John', 'Matt')`. The main query then selects all the records in the given date range where `Name NOT IN ('John', 'Matt')`.

Comment: This worked for me! I wanted to fetch unique visitors to a class between certain dates and this does the job!

Comment: Just one note: this will return one record per student. I'm not sure, if that's what you want.

Comment: I was about to put the same concern in the comment. I wanted it to return all records per student which is not the case with the above. Any suggestions on how to improve this to give all records? In my example above it should return both entries for Jane

Comment: Thanks. This one works. Appreciate if you could explain how it works!

Comment: @user3379221 Added some explanation (also modified the subquery condition to better match the one you requested in your question) , let me know, if something not clear.